# Dll files can not be treat as difference in SVN after update

Tags: svn

Some of Nuget dll files can not be treat as difference in SVN after updating, so I can't commit them.

Is there a way to force commit files in SVN?

Comment: Andy, can you explain what you mean by "auto commit"? I use SVN (though not Ankh) quite a bit, but I'mm unfamiliar with that concept. SVN by itself treats all files the same, so a DLL file should be no different. This may depend on whether your repository is setup with any `svn:ignore` properties.

Comment: SVN doesn't "auto commit" anything, so I'm not sure what you're asking here. You commit a DLL the same as any other file; they're not treated any differently at all.

Comment: Sorry my mean is it can't auto include the new dll when I commit full project. I've update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. you can exclude the `bin` directory from source control, and have nuget automatically pull down missing packages on build by [following this guide - Using Nuget Without Committing Packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

   You will need to delete and `svn:ignore` the `bin` folder to do this. When you check out a copy, the `bin` folder will be re-created and populated with your nuget packages, solution projects and any additional references.

   In my opinion, this is the cleanest option, because it relieves you of the burden of manually keeping binaries up to date.
2. SVN will be able to figure out if a file changes, so my guess is that you have some property or setting in your SVN client that is ignoring changes to some files. See some of these links for inspiration:

   - [svn ignore anymore changes to a file that is held/tracked by svn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9181016/4044587)
   - [Tortoise SVN : How to ignore bin contents from commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12913232/4044587)
   - [Must I still keep my 3rd party library binaries in source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4460838/4044587)